# Using D3.js with NodeJs and Express

Tags: node.js, express, d3.js

I am following this tutorial on NodeJs and Express http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/.

I need to display bar charts using D3 for data visualisation. I made some changes in app.'s file :

```
var d3 = require('d3');
app.get('/d3', routes.d3);
```

Added these lines to route/index.js:

```
exports.helloworld = function(req, res){
  res.render('d3');
};
```

Added a new file to views directory: d3.html containing code from index.html from this link
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304
and added data.tsv from same link.

I get this error:

```
/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:291
    throw new Error(msg);
          ^
Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at 
/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:291:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Router.route 
(/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:287:13)
    at Router.(anonymous function) [as get] (/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:318:16)
    at Function.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (/nodetest1/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:412:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/nodetest1/app.js:38:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Comment: Try with app.get('/d3', routes.helloWorld);

Comment: I found my mistake, in my routes/index.js I had two exports.helloworld. I modified one to exports.d3.  The app is running but now when I run localhost:3000/d3 it shows 500 Error: Failed to lookup view "d3" in views directory "/nodetest1/views"

Comment: I got that working too. had to use ejs(view engine for HTML).  But the html file is referring a data.tsv file which is in views directory but I am getting 404 error because it is not able to fetch it.

Comment: Put your data file under the public folder and make sure you use Express static middleware to allow for these static files to be fetched.

Answer (score -2):

```
var d3 = require('d3');
app.get('/d3', d3.helloworld);
```