# how to use d3.js code in express framework

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, d3.js

I want to visualize data using d3.js. So I connect express framework to postgresql from which i am getting user data which will be visualize using d3.js.
My question is that how I use pure d3.js code inside express framework?

Thank you.
Regards,
RAEES KHAN.
TU KL, Germany.

Comment: Render a view with placeholders, make a ajax call to get the required data, draw whatever using d3.

Comment: Could you please send me some examples or links. I have no idea. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Express is a web server like anybody else. d3.js runs in the web browser and does not care where it gets its data from.

- Create Express app.
- Connect to PostgreSQL.
- Write API end point.
- Return data to client.

PS: I went to FH KL.

Comment: I already created express app, connect to postgresql. I also make a histogram in d3.js. Now I don't know how to merge d3 code with express? Please send me some useful links or examples. if possible tell me about "writing api end point" ? what's that?

Comment: In my express framework/routes/index.js, I include 'var d3 = require('d3');' but after including the d3 library when I use d3 code like 'd3.select('body')....' it could not work

Comment: I think you are missing out on basic concepts of web development. You need to understand the difference between server and client.

Comment: I understand well about server and client. May be I could not convey my message to you correctly. My question is almost same as this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735481/using-d3-js-with-nodejs-and-express

Comment: That guy knows as little about the server/client paradigm as you. There are great teachers at TUKL. Ask for help!

Comment: ok thanks. I will. I can show you one example. php is server side, html is client side, mysql is database, we can fetch data from mysql using php and then show it in html. right? The same concept I want to apply on the express (server) , d3 (client) and postgresql (database).