# what is the difference between d3.js and d3.express

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know that d3.js is a  JavaScript framework used in data visualisation but I just saw the developer of d3.js announcing d3.express, so what is the difference?

Comment: It maybe d3 combine with express nodejs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735481/using-d3-js-with-nodejs-and-express

Answer (score 10, accepted):

solved: d3.express  is a reactive coding environment (whose name has [since changed](https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/913918215364820992) to ['Observable'](https://observablehq.com/)  (as in 'Observable Notebook')) for a realtime rendering & data-science applications of d3 code

Answer (score 3):

as of this moment of this writing, it's a project in the works, the goal is to establish data visualization coding environment, and a reactive aspect to it hence this will complement the d3 project.

Answer (score 0):

d3.express is an enviroment to help newbies to get up and runinning much faster, it's similar to the way ipython notebooks are to the python language.
Mike Bostock explain this much more in this article [link](https://medium.com/@mbostock/a-better-way-to-code-2b1d2876a3a0)